# django template image not showing with static

Tags: python, django, templates

I have static structure:

```
static
    js
    img
    css
    my_files
```

In my template when I do `<img src="{% static "{{ file.media_file }}" %}"` I am not getting image but when I do `<img src= "/static/{{file.media_file}}"` I am getting images..

How can I get using {% static %} format ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use template tags inside template tags. You mean just:

```
<img src="{% static file.media_file %}">
```